# GenericViewSet kwargs is empty

Tags: django, request, django-views, keyword-argument

I have a View Set which is inheriting from `GenericViewSet` and `ListModelMixin`.

I've implemented `get_queryset`, however I need to get url parameters to properly implement what I need to but `self.kwargs` is empty.

To check things out I removed the `ListModelMixin` and put an empty `list` method in it's place and just logged `args`, `kwargs`, and `request.GET`. request.GET did have the parameter, but args or kwargs were empty. How do I get them to populate into kwargs so that I can reference them in get_queryset?

I'm brand new to django by the way, and the biggest issue for me is that I just can't find any documentation on how args and kwargs are populated. I've been severely unimpressed with django's documentation

URL is registered with the following:

```
router.register(r'users', viewsets.CustomUserViewSet, base_name='user')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

My class:

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("kwargs: " + str(kwargs))
        logger.info("args: " + str(args))
        logger.info("GET: " + str(request.GET))
        logger.info("POST: " + str(request.POST))
        pass

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(~Q(pk=self.request.user.pk), Q(is_superuser=False), Q(is_active=True))
```

The intention is for get_queryset to further filter based on the value of a GET parameter.

Note: Obviously this gives me an error when I navigate to it as it doesn't return a response. But the logs is the point here

The log output from visiting "users/?arg=argval" is:

```
[23/Nov/2015 20:10:54] INFO [DjangoApp:171] kwargs: {}
[23/Nov/2015 20:10:54] INFO [DjangoApp:172] args: ()
[23/Nov/2015 20:10:54] INFO [DjangoApp:173] GET: <QueryDict: {u'arg': [u'argval']}>
[23/Nov/2015 20:10:54] INFO [DjangoApp:174] POST: <QueryDict: {}>
```

Comment: Please post some code. You're here for 3 years already. We expect you to know how it really works here :) Or anywhere for that matter.

Comment: @RohitJain Didn't post the code because it didn't provide anything over what I said. But thus, I've provided it regardless

Comment: You're already getting the query param in `request.GET` output?

Comment: @RohitJain I need it in get_queryset. And I don't understand why it would be in request.GET but not kwargs. I was under the impression that url params got put into kwargs

Comment: Just do: `self.request.query_params.get('arg')`. `kwargs` contains the `url` parameter, rather than query parameters.